# Question marks in Word mail merge if statement

Tags: mailmerge

I'm drafting a mail merge document that involves some if statements. In some conditions there are quotation marks in one of the output statements. Let me give an analogous example.

Imagine you're generating report cards, and you have a list of students and whether they've read chapter 9 of the textbook. If they've read the chapter, the output should read,

**Your daughter has read the chapter "Laplace's Contribution to Calculus"**
or
**Your daughter has not done the reading**

This can be coded as

{ IF { MERGEFIELD CHAPTERREAD } = "Y" "**Your daughter has read the chapter "Laplace's Contribution to Calculus"**" "**Your daughter has not done the reading**" }

except that the title of the chapter has quotation marks in it that interfere with the syntax of the if statement. How can I insert a set of quotation marks in the if statement?

Thanks for the help.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field with logic such as: “If Condition 1 is met, then if Condition 2 is also met, display Result 1”. This is equivalent to saying “if both conditions are met, display Result 1”; but unfortunately you can't use “and” in Word fields.

Such a field would look something this:

{ IF [Condition 1] { IF [Condition 2] [Display Result 1] "" } "" }

Comment: The issue isn't using multiple conditions, but getting quotation marks into the output.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of using a crude workaround. I put a field in my source data called QMARK. The whole column contains a quotation mark for each person. The if statement I'm now using is

{ IF { MERGEFIELD CHAPTERREAD } = "Y" "**Your daughter has read the chapter { MERGEFIELD QMARK }Laplace's Contribution to Calculus{ MERGEFIELD QMARK }**" "**Your daughter has not done the reading**" }

This definitely works, but if someone has a more elegant solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested field at the beginning of your document to set a bookmark to a double-quotation mark like this:

```
{ SET qmark { QUOTE 34 } }
```

Then in your text you can use

```
{ qmark }
```

(As usual you need to insert the special field code braces using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word)

Not much more elegant, but it saves putting an extra column in your data source.